# Agregar un signo positivo cuando el digito sea positivo

Tags: php, html5, webview

Tengo que digitar unos números de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego los tengo que guardar y al momento de imprimirlos me tiene que aparecer el signo positivo para los valores positivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es la parte del código de impresión, se que aquí tengo que agregar ese cambio.**

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px #e7e8ea;border-right:solid 1px #e7e8ea;"></td>
                        <td class="bordered">Curva Base</td>
                        <td class="bordered">Esfera</td>
                        <td class="bordered">Cilindro</td>
                        <td class="bordered">Eje</td>
                        <td class="bordered">ADD</td>
                    </tr>
               
                    <tr>
                        <td class="bordered">Ojo Derecho</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteCbOd()}</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteEsfOd()}</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteCilOd()}</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteEjeOd()}</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteAddOd()}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="bordered">Ojo Izquierdo</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteCbOi()}</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteEsfOi()}</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteCilOi()}</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteEjeOi()}</td>
                        <td class="bordered  bold">{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteAddOi()}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: cómo funciona esto? -> `$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteCbOd()`

Comment: funciona como se muestra en la segunda imagen pero sin el signo positivo, eso es lo que lo imprime.

Comment: ¿Tal vez usando un condicional?

Comment: No se conocen esos métodos `getLcLente...()`, pero se podría arreglar dentro de los mismos modificando los `return` por algo como: `return ($resultado > 0) ? "+$resultado" : "$resultado";`

Comment: Estas guardando a `"$resultado"` como un string... en ese caso sería `"+" + $resultado`

Comment: <td class="bordered  bold">+{$lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteCbOd()}</td> de esta manera ya me aparece el + pero si no digito el numero me sigue apareciendo el +, necesito no se si con una condicion que cuando no digito nada no me aparezca ese mas

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Me sirvió la función, pero la tengo que incluir en el html de otra manera a convertNum porque me aparece el error Object of class ContactLensesLens could not be converted to string in

Comment: @Yasa recuerda que si te sirvió la respuesta puedes verificarla para que tu pregunta esté como respondida. En caso tengas otro inconveniente, puedes realizar otra pregunta y así tendrás otras alternativas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una función que reciba como parámetro a las variables que tienes en tus tablas, en donde la función evalúa si el parámetro que recibe es negativo (retorna el mismo número), si es positivo (retorna el mismo número con el signo `+`) o que si es vacío o undefined (retorna un string vacío para ambos casos), por ejemplo:

```js
function convertNum(num){
  if (num !== '' && num !== undefined)
    return num < 0 ? (num) : ("+" + num);
  else
    return '';
}

console.log(convertNum(-1))
console.log(convertNum(''))
console.log(convertNum())
console.log(convertNum(1))
```

Y en tu HTML sería así:

```
<td class="bordered  bold">{convertNum($lenteProfe[0]->getLcLenteCbOd())}</td>
```